# NetPlan: multiple IPs with multiple gateways

Tags: linux-networking, netplan

I'm trying to add additional IPs linked to different gateways to my server. I'm following the example for, "Using multiple addresses with multiple gateways" from netplan.io/Examples

> Invalid YAML: mapping values are not allowed in this context:
> via: 112.39.226.209

My netplan config file looks like this (I've modified some numbers for security purposes):
network:

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    ens160:
     addresses:
        - 111.225.4.42/28
        - 111.225.8.119/30
        - 112.39.226.210/28
     routes:
        - to: default
          via: 111.225.4.33
          metric: 200
        - to: default
          via: 111.225.8.113
          metric: 300
        - to: default
          via: 112.39.226.209
          metric: 400
     nameservers:
        addresses: [ "8.8.4.4", "8.8.8.8" ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a friend and it turns out I didn't need to specify the routes / alternate gateways at all so the yaml file ended up being:

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    ens160:
     addresses:
        - 111.225.4.42/28
        - 111.225.8.119/30
        - 112.39.226.210/28
     gateway4: 111.225.4.33
     nameservers:
        addresses: [ "8.8.4.4", "8.8.8.8" ]
```